How do I send an react-native Expo EAS Update to a specific build or version of my app?
I'm working with Expo EAS (Expo Application Services) and I need to deploy an update specifically to a certain build or version of my app. I know that Expo EAS Update allows for over-the-air updates, but I’m unsure how to target a specific build or version with these updates.
